# Import vlookup data from a seperate Google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-vlookup, importrange

I have a g-sheet and need to link cells from a imported g-sheet while using the `vlookup` formula. However, I can’t get it to work...

This is my formula:

```
=vlookup($A781,IMPORTRANGE("(link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1migJfXvK29d2bUm0pgZQQco-dOlAoNzfVoCrjIJ--uY/edit#gid=1509040177) docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d…",'SDC & MVC'!$A$1:$G,4,false))
```

This is my error message:

> Wrong number of arguments to VLOOKUP.  Expected between 3 and 4
>   arguments, but got 2 arguments

Any suggestions?  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The `vlookup` function takes 3 or 4 arguments and you have only provided two. I think you might need a closing parentheses `)` on the `IMPORTRANGE` earlier before `SDC & MVC'!$A$1:$G`.

Try:

```
=vlookup($A781,IMPORTRANGE("(link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1migJfXvK29d2bUm0pgZQQco-dOlAoNzfVoCrjIJ--uY/edit#gid=1509040177) docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d…"),'SDC & MVC'!$A$1:$G,4,false)
```

Argments are as follows:

> Search_key - is the value to search for (lookup value or unique
>   identifier). For example, you can search for the word "apple", number
>   10, or the value in cell A2.
>
> Range - two or more columns of data for the search. The Google Sheets
>   VLOOKUP function always searches in the first column of range.
>
> Index - the column number in range from which a matching value (value in the same row as search_key) should be returned.
>        The first column in range has index 1. If index is less than 1, a Vlookup formula returns the #VALUE! error. If it's greater than the
>   number of columns in range, VLOOKUP returns the #REF! error.
>
> Is_sorted - indicates whether your Vlookup formula should return the
>   nearest match (TRUE) or exact match (FALSE).

Source: https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2017/07/05/vlookup-google-sheets-example/

Comment: Thank you!  It didn't work but I think we're close.  I will keep trying.

Answer (score 0):

correct syntax would be:

```
=VLOOKUP(A781, 
 IMPORTRANGE("1migJfXvK29d2bUm0pgZQQco-dOlAoNzfVoCrjIJ--uY", "SDC & MVC!A1:G"), 4, 0)
```

eg: find value of cell **A781** in spreadsheet with ID **`1migJfXvK29d2bUm0pgZQQco-dOlAoNzfVoCrjIJ--uY`** in sheet called **SDC & MVC** in column **A** ...and if match is found return adjacent value from column **D** (4th column)